# Copy list initialization

Tags: c++11

I am learning C++, but there is a problem about copy initialization which really confuses me. The following is the class that I created.

```
class Example{
public:
    Example(initializer_list<int> il) {cout<<"constructor"<<endl;}
    Example(const char *) {cout<<"constructor"<<endl;}
    Example(const Example &) {cout<<"copy constructor"<<endl;}
};
```

Constructor and copy constructor will be called if the code looks like this, Example ex = "Hello world". However, if the code is Example ex = {0,1,2,3}, only constructor will be called, not copy constructor. Any explains? I'd really appreciate.

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://rextester.com/ORG80803). For `Example ex = "Hello world";`, copy constructor is not called.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I added -fno-elide-constructors flag to g++. It will turn off the compiler optimization. Mine is like this, "g++ -std=c++0x -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fno-elide-constructors ....".